# At what rate and to what extent do metabolic waste products from neurons diffuse throughout the brain?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, brain, mental-exhaustion

At what rate and to what extent do metabolic waste products from neurons diffuse throughout the brain?

Do the metabolic waste products remain local to the neurons being used, or do those waste products diffuse throughout the brain?